# Sending my Lambda function's event cross account to my EventBridge Rule

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-event-bridge

I've got two cloudformation templates written, with the intention of limiting spend by automatically applying an SCP on any account within an org if a budget is triggered in said account.

The management account stack has an event bus and rule and a lambda which will actually apply the SCP, and the member account stack is meant to be deployed as a stack set across multiple accounts - whenever i test the member account lambda which should trigger the management account eventbridge rule / lambda function to carry out the SCP application, it hits the eventbus (therefore it's not a permissions issue) but doesn't trigger the rule - would anyone mind taking a look? i've got about as far as I can. I think it's to do with the way the event is being passed / consumed. p.s you'll need an SCP in your management account to test this.

happy to answer any questions!

Management Template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Centralized Event Bus
  - Located in the management (payer) account.
  - Designed to receive events from all member accounts.

  Lambda Function for Account Restriction
  - Triggered by the centralized EventBridge bus when a budget alert is received.
  - Moves the account that exceeded its budget to a restrictive OU.

  EventBridge Rule
  - Listens to the centralized event bus for specific budget alert events.
  - Triggers the Lambda function responsible for moving accounts to the restrictive OU.

  SNS Topic for Notification
  - Used to notify relevant stakeholders when an account is moved to the restrictive OU.

  Centralized IAM Lambda role
  - Used by the member account lambda functions to assume to carry out various organization related API calls

Parameters:
  SubscriptionEndPoint:
    Type: String
    Description: The endpoint that receives notifications.

  SubscriptionProtocol:
    Type: String
    Description: The subscription protocol
    AllowedValues:
      - email
      - email-json
      - application
      - lambda
    Default: email

  OrgID:
    Type: String
    Description: The principal Org ID Id of your AWS Organization.

  DenyAllSCPId:
    Type: String  
    Description: The ID of the existing Deny All SCP

Resources:
  LambdaRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Principal:
              Service: "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            Action: "sts:AssumeRole"
      Description: "Allowing Lambda account mover to work."
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: lambda-role-account-mover
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                  - "organizations:MoveAccount"
                  - "organizations:ListAccounts"
                  - "organizations:ListOrganizationalUnitsForParent"
                  - "organizations:DescribeOrganizationalUnit"
                  - "organizations:DescribeAccount"
                  - "organizations:AttachPolicy"
                Resource: "*"
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
      RoleName: lambda-role-account-mover

  LambdaInvokePermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !GetAtt AccountMover.Arn
      Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
      Principal: "events.amazonaws.com"
      SourceArn: !GetAtt BudgetRestrictorEventBus.Arn



  AccountMover:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: "account_mover"
      Environment:
        Variables:
          SCPId: !Ref DenyAllSCPId
    
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          import boto3
          import json
          import os
          import logging

          logger = logging.getLogger()
          logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

          def lambda_handler(event, context):
              logger.info(f"Received event: {json.dumps(event)}")

              # Access detail directly (it's already a dictionary)
              detail = event.get('detail')
              if not detail:
                  logger.error("Missing 'detail' field in the event.")
                  return {"statusCode": 400, "body": "Invalid event format"}

              account_id = detail.get('account_id')
              source_ou_id = detail.get('source_ou_id')

              if not account_id or not source_ou_id:
                  logger.error("Missing account_id or source_ou_id in the event detail.")
                  return {"statusCode": 400, "body": "Invalid event detail"}


              client = boto3.client('organizations')

              # Specify the Deny All SCP ID (You need to replace this with the actual SCP ID)
              deny_all_scp_id = os.environ['SCPId']


              try:
                  # Attach the Deny All SCP to the source OU
                  response = client.attach_policy(
                      PolicyId=deny_all_scp_id,
                      TargetId=source_ou_id
                  )
                  logger.info(f"Successfully attached Deny All SCP to OU {source_ou_id}")
                  return {"statusCode": 200, "body": json.dumps(response)}
              except Exception as e:
                  logger.error(f"Error in attaching SCP: {str(e)}")
                  return {"statusCode": 500, "body": json.dumps({"error": str(e)})}



      Handler: index.lambda_handler
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaRole.Arn
      Runtime: python3.11
      Timeout: 300


  BudgetRestrictorEventBus:
    Type: AWS::Events::EventBus
    Properties:
      Name: "BudgetRestrictorEventBus"

  BudgetRestrictorEventBusPolicy:
    Type: AWS::Events::EventBusPolicy
    Properties:
      StatementId: "AllowAllAccountsFromOrganizationToPutEvents"
      EventBusName: !Ref BudgetRestrictorEventBus
      Action: "events:PutEvents"
      Principal: "*"
      Condition:
        Type: "StringEquals"
        Key: "aws:PrincipalOrgID"
        Value: !Ref OrgID

  BudgetAlertRule:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      Description: "Trigger Lambda function for account movement on budget alert"
      EventBusName: !Ref BudgetRestrictorEventBus
      EventPattern:
        source:
          - "lambda.BudgetAlertForwarder"
      State: "ENABLED"
      Targets:
        - Arn: !GetAtt AccountMover.Arn
          Id: "AccountMoverTarget"

  SNSTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties: {}

  SNSSubscription:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
    Properties:
      Endpoint: !Ref SubscriptionEndPoint
      Protocol: !Ref SubscriptionProtocol
      TopicArn: !Ref SNSTopic

  CrossAccountRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Principal:
              AWS: "*" # Allows any principal within AWS to assume this role
            Action: "sts:AssumeRole"
      Path: "/"
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: "OrganizationManagementPolicy"
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                  - "organizations:MoveAccount"
                  - "organizations:ListAccounts"
                  - "organizations:ListOrganizationalUnitsForParent"
                  - "organizations:DescribeOrganizationalUnit"
                  - "organizations:DescribeAccount"
                  - "organizations:ListAccountsForParent"
                  - "organizations:AttachPolicy"
                Resource: "*"
              - Sid: "Logging"  
                Effect: "Allow"
                Action: 
                  - "logs:CreateLogGroup"
                Resource: 
                  - !Sub "arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:*"
              - Sid: "CreateLogStream"  
                Effect: "Allow"
                Action: 
                  - "logs:CreateLogStream"
                  - "logs:PutLogEvents"
                Resource: 
                  - "*"  
      RoleName: "CrossAccountOrganizationRole"

Outputs:
  BudgetRestrictorEventBusArn:
    Description: "ARN of the Centralized Budget Restrictor EventBus"
    Value: !GetAtt BudgetRestrictorEventBus.Arn
  CrossAccountRoleArn:
    Description: "ARN of the CrossAccountRole for the lambda functions in the member accounts to assume."
    Value: !GetAtt CrossAccountRole.Arn
```

Member Account Template

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: "Member Account Budget and Event Forwarding Setup"

Parameters:
  BudgetAmountPerMonth:
    Type: Number
    Description: "The total budget value per account in USD, per month (which will trigger an account quarantine process.)"

  CentralEventBusArn:
    Type: String
    Description: "ARN of the Centralized Event Bus in the Management Account"

  OrgRootId:
    Type: String
    Description: "Root ID of the AWS Organization"

  CrossAccountRoleArn:
    Type: String
    Description: "ARN of the Cross Account Role in the Management Account"

  ManagementAccountId:
    Type: String
    Description: "The AWS Account ID of the Management Account."


Resources:
  BudgetExample:
    Type: "AWS::Budgets::Budget"
    Properties:
      Budget:
        BudgetLimit:
          Amount: !Ref BudgetAmountPerMonth
          Unit: USD
        TimeUnit: MONTHLY
        BudgetType: COST
      NotificationsWithSubscribers:
        - Notification:
            NotificationType: ACTUAL
            ComparisonOperator: GREATER_THAN
            Threshold: 100
          Subscribers:
            - SubscriptionType: SNS
              Address: !Ref SNSTopicForBudget

  SNSTopicForBudget:
    Type: "AWS::SNS::Topic"
    Properties:
      TopicName: "BudgetExceededTopic"

  SNSTopicSubscription:
    Type: "AWS::SNS::Subscription"
    Properties:
      Protocol: "lambda"
      Endpoint: !GetAtt BudgetAlertLambda.Arn
      TopicArn: !Ref SNSTopicForBudget

  SNSTopicPolicy:
    Type: AWS::SNS::TopicPolicy
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: budgets.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - SNS:Publish
            Resource: !Ref SNSTopicForBudget
      Topics:
        - Ref: SNSTopicForBudget

  LambdaInvokePermission:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Permission"
    Properties:
      Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
      FunctionName: !GetAtt BudgetAlertLambda.Arn
      Principal: "sns.amazonaws.com"
      SourceArn: !Ref SNSTopicForBudget

  BudgetAlertLambdaRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Principal:
              Service: "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            Action: "sts:AssumeRole"
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: "LambdaBudgetAlertPolicy"
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                  - "events:PutEvents"
                Resource: !Ref CentralEventBusArn

              - Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                  - "organizations:ListOrganizationalUnitsForParent"
                  - "organizations:DescribeOrganizationalUnit"
                  - "organizations:ListAccountsForParent"
                Resource: "*"

              - Effect: "Allow"
                Action: "sts:AssumeRole"
                Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${ManagementAccountId}:role/CrossAccountOrganizationRole"

  BudgetAlertLambda:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Function"
    Properties:
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          import boto3
          import json
          import os
          import logging

          # Setting up logging
          logger = logging.getLogger()
          logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

          def assume_role(arn, session_name):
              sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
              assumed_role_object = sts_client.assume_role(
                  RoleArn=arn,
                  RoleSessionName=session_name
              )
              credentials = assumed_role_object['Credentials']
              return boto3.Session(
                  aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],
                  aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
                  aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken'],
              )

          def lambda_handler(event, context):
              # Log the start of the function
              logger.info("Lambda function has started.")

              # Retrieve environment variables
              cross_account_role_arn = os.getenv('CROSS_ACCOUNT_ROLE_ARN')
              central_event_bus_arn = os.getenv('CENTRAL_EVENT_BUS_ARN')

              logger.info(f"Assuming role: {cross_account_role_arn}")
              session = assume_role(cross_account_role_arn, 'BudgetAlertSession')
              org_client = session.client('organizations')

              # Log the retrieval of the account ID and source OU ID
              account_id = context.invoked_function_arn.split(":")[4]
              logger.info(f"Retrieved account ID: {account_id}")

              source_ou_id = get_source_ou_id(org_client, account_id)
              if not source_ou_id:
                  logger.error(f"OU ID for account {account_id} not found.")
                  return {"statusCode": 404, "body": "OU ID not found"}
              logger.info(f"Retrieved source OU ID: {source_ou_id}")
              
              # Modify the event payload structure
              event_payload = {
                  'Source': 'lambda.BudgetAlertForwarder',
                  'DetailType': 'Budget Alert',
                  'Detail': {
                      'account_id': account_id,
                      'source_ou_id': source_ou_id
                  },
                  'EventBusName': central_event_bus_arn
              }
              
              # Convert the entire payload to JSON string before sending
              payload_to_send = json.dumps(event_payload)
              
              # Log the full event payload for debugging
              logger.info(f"Full event payload being sent to EventBridge: {payload_to_send}")
              
              # Instantiate the EventBridge client
              eventbridge_client = boto3.client('events')
              
              # Send the event to the central EventBridge bus
              response = eventbridge_client.put_events(
                  Entries=[{
                      'Source': event_payload['Source'],
                      'DetailType': event_payload['DetailType'],
                      'Detail': json.dumps(event_payload['Detail']),
                      'EventBusName': event_payload['EventBusName']
                  }]
              )
              
              logger.info(f"Event sent to EventBridge: {response}")
              return response

          def get_source_ou_id(client, account_id):
              # Retrieve the root ID from the environment variables
              org_root_id = os.getenv('ORG_ROOT_ID')

              # Iterate through all OUs to find which one contains the account
              paginator = client.get_paginator('list_organizational_units_for_parent')
              for page in paginator.paginate(ParentId=org_root_id):
                  for ou in page['OrganizationalUnits']:
                      if account_in_ou(client, account_id, ou['Id']):
                          return ou['Id']
              return None

          def account_in_ou(client, account_id, ou_id):
              # Check if the specified account is in the specified OU
              paginator = client.get_paginator('list_accounts_for_parent')
              for page in paginator.paginate(ParentId=ou_id):
                  for account in page['Accounts']:
                      if account['Id'] == account_id:
                          return True
              return False

      FunctionName: "BudgetAlertForwarder"
      Handler: "index.lambda_handler"
      Role: !GetAtt BudgetAlertLambdaRole.Arn
      Runtime: "python3.11"
      Timeout: 300
      Environment:
        Variables:
          CENTRAL_EVENT_BUS_ARN: !Ref CentralEventBusArn
          ORG_ROOT_ID: !Ref OrgRootId
          CROSS_ACCOUNT_ROLE_ARN: !Ref CrossAccountRoleArn
```

I tried to send an event from a single account to my EventBridge Event bus in my management account.